# Force datasource to reload data in Angular 2 grid

Tags: angular, binding, grid, refresh, datasource

I am using Angular 2 and have a grid (ag-grid-angular) with `enableServerSideSorting=true` and it's working fine only for the first time: the data is loaded and placed in the grid view as expected. When I click on a column to sort that column (which happens automatically) the data is fetched again by calling `getRows(params)`.

The problem is that I have several other input fields:

- Tabs: to change the type of elements displayed (for example persons or cars).
- Text field: which is used to enter search criteria.

When I change these input fields, how can I force datasource to collect data again from the server? If I change the tab or search field, then the correct data is only fetched again after I press on one of the columns (forcing to sort again).

I tried `this.agGrid.api.refreshView()` in the method that is triggered by changing the tab, but this ofcourse does not work.

Comment: The solution according to the documentation of ag-grid (which I overlooked) is to assign the datasource to itself again. This will trigger a refresh of data: `this.agGrid.setDatasource(this.datasource)`

Comment: A very odd way of doing things, but it works, and undocumented too. Why there isn't just a call "refreshDataSource" is a mystery. There are many occasions when I need to send for the data again as there are too many rows to return over 3g/4g. Thanks for your answer.